# Accessing WMS layer that requires authorization via OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, authentication

Is there a way to send username and password parameter to a wms layer that needs authorization?

If not, I guess it's perhaps a non-spatial thing to solve so that you before the javascript sends a wms request you initiate a httprequest to the server where the wms service is hosted.

If you use firefox you could add http:\username:password@wmsurl and its solved and the information is the stored in the session/cache ...

Answer (score 2):

It's not the work of WMS server that do the authorization, but the HTTP server. Usually we save logged in user's information in the sessions and provide those information when requesting to a WMS server in the cookies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the best solution, and for now I have only managaged to get it to work on IE 8 (because of cross site scripting), but it works for now. If anybody have a solution to solve the cross site scripting it would be great.
This solution will also mean that the username and password will vissible in the javascript, but thats not an issue for me.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax(
                {
                  'password' : 'your_password',
                  'username' : 'your_username',
                  'url'      : url,
                  'type'     : 'POST',
                  'success'  : function(){   },
                  'error'    : function(err){ },
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [OpenLayers and http basic authentication](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41491).

A possible solution (my answer there) is to do an ajax call to the WMS service, and let the browser to handle the http authentication, and add the layer after the user is authenticated