# Access secured WMS server in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms, security

I browsed regarding this question and I couldn't find any better solution. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41491/openlayers-2-12-and-http-basic-authentication-woes/43526#43526) link has some information for OpenLayers but not for Leaflet.

How do I access a secured WMS via Leaflet in with JavaScript? Do I need to pass user name and password as parameter? Does Leaflet support access to secured WMS server?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps somebody...there is a useful plugin to set auth in leaflet wms request headers. Hopefully that solves the problem.

[leaflet-wms-header](https://github.com/ticinum-aerospace/leaflet-wms-header)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself after some time.

1) Yes, Leaflet does support access to secured wms server.
2) I included username and password in the url and it worked in chrome and firefox.

```
L.tileLayer.wms("https://uname:pwd@services.website.com?axyz",{})
```

Now, I am trying to access the server without exposing username and password in java script and also without using proxy server.

Comment: This no longer works in chrome. It blocks requests containing authorisation credentials in the URL for subresources :(

Comment: Any idea of an actual approach for that issue?